# How to create Image Action Link Html helper in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How can i create action image html helper in asp.net mvc like below..

```
@Html.ActionImage("actionName", "controllerName", "routeValues")
```

similarly like below helper...

```
@Html.Action("actionName", "controllerName", "routeValues")
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: what's your problem with Action? You always can create controller that returns image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom helper class like..

```
 namespace MyNamespace 
 {  
    public static class MyHeleprs
    { 
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper html, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string imagePath, string alt)
         {
             var url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

            // build the <img> tag
            var imgBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
            imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", url.Content(imagePath));
            imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
            string imgHtml = imgBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

            // build the <a> tag
            var anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");

            anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(action, controllerName, routeValues));
            anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml; // include the <img> tag inside
            string anchorHtml = anchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorHtml);
         } 
    } 
}
```

To make this helper available in your view, add its namespace as follows:

```
@using MyNamespace
```

Now you can get html helper in your views like below...

```
@Html.ActionImage(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, imagePath, imgAlt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [custom Html helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs):

```
public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string action, string controller, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes,string imageSrc)
{
                var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
                var img = new TagBuilder("img");
                img.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(imageSrc));
                var anchor = new TagBuilder("a") { InnerHtml = img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) };
                anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues);
                anchor.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

                return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());

}
```